# Equals string with value item of NSCombobox

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscombobox

I want get index of value item of NSCombobox if string equals it.
My code is add item for NSCombobox :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; ++i)
{
   [combox addItemWithObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

I don't know how to count value item of `NSCombobox`. Do you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try `indexOfItemWithObjectValue:` method? See [NSComboBox Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html)